# How can you write a dict lookup to a csv from mysql with python

Tags: python, mysql

I write this csv from a mysql db tabel in this way:

```html
with open('outfile','w') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    for row in cursor.fetchall():
        writer.writerow(row)
```

This will output this csv :

```html
34,0.0,2016-04-07 14:51:16
8,59.08,2016-04-07 16:55:26
55,207.76,2016-04-08 06:24:42
37,247.14,2016-04-08 07:50:02
40,255.35,2016-04-08 07:58:51
49,480.26,2016-04-08 08:11:31
```

And I have created this lookup dict like this :

```html
machine_lookup = {}
for row in rows:
    machine_lookup[row['id']] = str(row['mr_machine_id'])
```

This dict look like:

```html
{34: '1137', 8: '1125', 55: '1139', 37: '1140', 40: '1124', 40: '1138'}
```

How I can edit my initial csv creator:

```html
with open('outfile','w') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    for row in cursor.fetchall():
        writer.writerow(row)
```

to insert the first row as in the dict lookup in order to output my csv file to look like this :

```html
1137,0.0,2016-04-07 14:51:16
1125,59.08,2016-04-07 16:55:26
1139,207.76,2016-04-08 06:24:42
1140,247.14,2016-04-08 07:50:02
1124,255.35,2016-04-08 07:58:51
1138,480.26,2016-04-08 08:11:31
```

Answer (score 0):

Since each row is a list. You can modify it in-place, or create a new list with the value you want to replace with.
for example:

```
row[0] = value
```

In your code you can do like this.

```
with open('outfile','w') as f:
writer = csv.writer(f)
for row in cursor.fetchall():
    row[0] = str(row['mr_machine_id'])
    writer.writerow(row)
```

Comment: tuple indices must be integers, not str on this line row[0] = str(row['mr_machine_id']), evan if I replace str with int.